# Character set with std::string, cout, ofstream and sockets

Tags: c++, string, character-encoding, stream

I'm trying to send strings over a windows socket connection that contain characters like "á" that are outside the ASCII table. I hear garbage comming out the other end when I try something like this:

```
std::string message("á");
retval = send(conn_socket, message.c_str(), message.length(), 0);
```

So I started investigating and I came across the need to encode using something like UTF8. While I'm still looking for a simple way to do this in C++, I have a question about the streams behavior I noticed:

How come `std::ofstream << message` will correctly output `á`, while `cout << message` will output garbage? What's the difference between the 2? Can I use this to my advantage when sending these characters over a socket?

Answer (score 0):

When you write to a file with `std::ofstream` the bytes representing the characters are being written to the file directly, and the application that opens the file is responsible for converting those bytes back to a character. When you write to `cout` the console will interpret the bytes into a character. The console and an application do not have to agree on the byte encoding; the Windows console in particular will insist on a code page interpretation, even if you would rather wish for UTF-8.

Comment: Is that why it also gets screwed up when I send my std::string over a socket using only s.c_str()? What is the correct way to send the string over a socket?

Comment: @FernandoFaria, both sides of the socket need to agree on the byte encoding for a character. Without knowing how the string is generated or how it is used on the other end, the question is impossible to answer. The socket itself won't change the string at all.

Comment: thanks for the reply! I think I got the gist of it already... my last question would be, what is considered an elegant way to combine utf-8 with std::string's? I understand each element in a std::string will no longer be a character, I'm just wondering what I would use to accomplish something like std::string s(utf8(_U("áéíóú));... Thanks!!!

Comment: @FernandoFaria, until C++11 there isn't an easy way to create UTF-8 string literals. You can use the `\x` notation to specify each byte, but that's awkward and ugly. Or you can create your C++ source file in UTF-8 and hope the compiler doesn't try to reinterpret the characters as it builds the string.